# Quickly navigate through data with SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, ssms

I'm a developer who works a lot in an environment with lots of FK relations.

When I'm developing my application, I would like the ability to quickly navigate through data.
I'll explain it through an example :)

```
Table - Car
ID TypeID CarName ...
1   1     A
2   1     B
3   2     C
```

I would get this data if I did a "SELECT * FROM car". The problem is that I only get a limit amount of data. I don't know which Type Car A is, I only know its TypeID.

How I handle this now, is by either writing an extended SQL query (inner join it with type and also include the name) or by doing a SELECT * FROM type where ID = 1.

I'd like to be able to have this data presented to me quickly (and I'm not talking about a regular view). I would like to write an extension on SQL management studio, in which I would check if the table had a FK-relation. If it's filled in, I'd then give a tooltip if I hover over the FK-cell.

The question: is this possible? Can I write extensions on SQL Management studio? Does something like this already exist within SQL Mang studio or any third party packages?
If it doesn't exist, but I can make it, how would I go about doing it?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: SSMS tools pack is a SQL Management studio add on, so it is definately possible - http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is a c# scratchpad that speaks LINQ2SQL.
I use it a lot to query data.
You can quite easily mix LINQ2SQL and c# code to do more advanced queries and calculations than possible in plain SQL.

The free version works OK, but if you pay you get autocompletion too.

Comment: Thanks! I'm definitely going to use it! I love LINQ ;)

Comment: @Team-JoKi, it sounds like you are already up to speed with LINQ, then you will have a pretty quick learning curve.